# Function error comparing radio button results to array value

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, radio-button

I'm trying to check an answer from radio buttons. There are only two option, I'm trying to use selectedIndex and then check the answer with a value put in another array. The question and answer arrays are both working fine, but regardless of the answer that is checked, the function considers it the correct one and adds a score to my global score counter variable. The answers array contains only the numbers 1 or 2 in each slot depending on the question, so I'm not sure why it's not working.

```
function checkAnswer0() 
{
if((document.getElementById('trueorfalse0').selectedIndex = 1) && (answersPushed[0]         == 1))
{
    scoreCounter++;
    document.getElementById("warning").innerHTML = "Correct Answer";
} 

else if((document.getElementById('trueorfalse0').selectedIndex = 2) && (answersPushed[0] == 2))
{
    scoreCounter++;
    document.getElementById("warning").innerHTML = "Correct Answer";    
}

else{
    document.getElementById("warning").innerHTML = "Wrong Answer";
    }
```

}

My form section looks like this and is held in the body within form tags.

```
<input name="Answer0" type="radio" id="trueorfalse0" value="true" onclick="checkAnswer0()"/> True <br/>
<input name="Answer0" type="radio" id="trueorfalse0" value="false" onclick="checkAnswer0()" /> False
```

If anyone can help me understand the nature of the problem I'd appreciate it. I know there are many alternative ways to have approached the problem but I'd like to sort out in my head why this one isn't happening for me. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

<del>I suspect the first part of your if condition should look like `if((document.getElementById('trueorfalse0').selectedIndex == 1) && ...`, notice the extra **=**, for it to make sense.</del>

**EDIT**

selectedIndex is a property of select input. To check if radio input is checked, you have to loop over group of inputs and check the value of `checked` property.

```
var answers = document.getElementById('trueorfalse0');
var value;
for(var i = 0; i < answers.length; i++){
  if(answers[i].checked){
    value = answers[i].value;
  }
}
```

Comment: I've tried it and while I understand your point I'm afraid my core problem still exists, any other thought?

Comment: Updated the answer, you can't use `selectedIndex` for what you want to do.